# how to update the results of a component's query based on the results of an other component's subscription?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, scaphold

I have 2 react components on the same page,

- Component 1 query a list of users
- Component 2 subscribe to the event
  of creating a new user

I can’t figure out a way to update the results of the component 1 based on the results of component 2's subscription.
Component1:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.data.loading? <span>loading…</span>
        : <span> //show the list of users </span>       }
        </div>
                    );
    }
}

export default graphql(queryAllUsers)(Comp1) ;
```

Component2 :

```
class Comp2 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
        this.state = {
        newUserCreated: false
            }
   }
 subscribeToNewUser() {
    this.subscription = this.props.data.subscribeToMore({
        document: subscribeToNewUsersQuery,
        variables: {//        },
    });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.newUserCreated}
        </div>
                    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a reducer function with query of the first component:

```js
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
  render() { ... }
}

export default graphql(queryAllUsers, {
      options: (ownProps) => {
        return ({
            variables: { ...
            },
            reducer: (previousResult, action) => {
              if (action.type === "APOLLO_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT" && action.operationName === "subscribeToNewUsersQuery") {
                //update the previousResult
                return previousResultWithNewData;
              } else return previousResult;
            })
        }
      })(Comp1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way is to use the query in the first component too and add the subscription to it via the `subscribeToMore` function.

Could look like this:

```js
...

subscribeToNewUser() {
    this.subscription = this.props.queryAllUsers.subscribeToMore({
      document: subscribeToNewUsersQuery,
      variables: { /* your variables */ },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
        const changedItem = subscriptionData.data.<subscriptionName>;
        if (changedItem !== undefined && changedItem !== null) {
          return // update previous result
        }
        return previousResult;
      },
    });
  }


  ...

  export default graphql(queryAllUsers, {
    name: "queryAllUsers"
  })
  ...
  (Comp1)
```

Therein you have the `updateQuery` functionality which will be called on the subscription event. When the resulting data is good you can update the store, e.g. push the new value to the users array

Comment: yes this could work, but for some performance reasons I want to have only 1 subscription done by the Comp1 only, and edit other component's queries according to that subscription.

Comment: Than you could check the reducer functionality of the query [short reducer docu](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#resultReducers). Here you could catch the subscription action type and the related subscription and update the store

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.